# Compress rows with same id

Tags: java, arrays, object

Hi i'm trying to loop through this structure:

```
id string1 string2 different_string
1  test    test      asd
1  test    test      dsa
2  data    data      qwe
3  info    info      ewq
3  info    info      zxc
3  info    info      qaz
```

I have rows with the exact same value but one of them is different so I'm trying to compress that data into a single row.

This is my code:

```
            int actual_id = list.get(0).num(); //I pick the first id = 1
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                if(list.get(i).id == actual_id){
                    String str = list.get(i).different_string;
                    items.add(str);
                    listOLists.add(items);
                    items.clear();
                }else {
                    actual_id = list.get(i).id;
                    i--;    
                }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < listOLists.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(listOLists);
            }
```

First I check  the id of each row and compare it with the actual value, I'm adding the string to an array and then append it to a list so I can store my data then reset the array to append new data to it and repeat the process, the problem is when I reset the array the loop doesn't seem to add more items to the list, what am I doing wrong?

this is I would like to get something like this:

```
{1, test, test, {asd, dsa}},{2, data, data, {asd}},{3, info, info, {ewq, zxc,qaz}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little difficult to follow but from what I can tell, your problem lies in this part of the code:

```
if(list.get(i).id == actual_id){
                String str = list.get(i).different_string;
                items.add(str);
                listOLists.add(items);
                items.clear();
            }else {
```

You add `items` to `listOList`, but in the next line you clear it. `items` still refers to the List you just added to `listOList` so when you clear it, it clears the list in `listOList` as well. You may want to declare `items` within the `if` block so a new List will be created each pass through the loop like this:

```
if(list.get(i).id == actual_id){
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            String str = list.get(i).different_string;
            items.add(str);
            listOLists.add(items);
        }else {
```

This way, a new `List` is being created every iteration through the loop avoiding the issue. I can't tell if this will solve all you're problems but I hope this gets you headed in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for the advice, As you mention the list was getting cleared at `listOList` too, I managed to fix it using another list and clone the list I was trying to insert